# How can I pass an emoji as POST request to Django and store it in MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am developing a chat application in Django. I am using MySQL database to store data. I want to store emojis also in the database

Input field:

```
<input type="text" name="message" onkeyup="handleChange(event, this)">
```

`handleChange` function:

```
function handleChange(event, elem){
    if(event.key=='Enter'){
        $.post('/new/',
         {
          data: elem.value
         });
     }
}
```

and in `views.py`,

```
def new(request):
    msg = request.POST.get('data')
    message = Message(message=msg)
    message.save()
```

Comment: Too broad a question. Show some code and why its not working. You'll need UTF8-MB4 character set on the data location where you store the emojis.

Comment: in my js file: $.post('/new/',{data:input})   --- And in views.py file... msg = Message(message = request.POST.get('data')) ; msg.save()

Comment: edit the question rather than trying ti include information in the limited comment space. Include why its not working as expected in your question.

Comment: @danblack please answer

Comment: Where's the database structure? What does `message.save()` actually do? "Show .. why its not working", please answer.

Comment: whenever I type simple text, it gets displayed in the database, but in case of emoji, it does nothing

Comment: message.save() saves the message in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217355/discussion-between-talha-quddoos-and-danblack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python emojis can print in string like this

```
print("\U0001f600")
```

You have to send Emoji string to python views.py function
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-emojis/